# How to fetch images from URL on WebView in iOS

Tags: ios, image, url, webview, fetch

[image]

image code -  1wba395mv72m3of2ikz.jpg

I used this.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.imageurlhost.com/viewer.php?file=1wba395mv72m3of2ikz.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIImageView *imgview1 =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150,150 )];

imgview1.image= image;

[scrlview addSubview:imgview1];
```

Comment: Well you will need to parse the HTML return from that URL and look for the image. Then when you have the image URL load the `UIImage` from that.

Comment: @rckoenes: url returns image or anything other?

Comment: @preetam If you had opened one of the URLs from the post you would have seen that it load a webpage.

Comment: @rckoenes: yup...i thought it is image url...

Answer (score 0):

you can set the image in image view like this

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url string"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```

placeholder.png is any temporary image which is replaced when image from url is received

Answer (score 0):

Rahul paliwal ...Your url is html page..if you want load image in imageview use proper url...
   if u want load image in imagview...like 
this...

[image]